# How to implement Row_Number() over (Partition By Order By) in EntityFramework Core 5?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table and fields as following
**Table**

```
T {
  RunDate datetime,
  A varchar,
  B varchar,
  C varchar,
  D varchar,
  E varchar,
}
```

I want to run the Sql with LINQ

**SQL**

```
Select 
    t.*
From 
    (
        SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A,B,C,D ORDER BY RunDate DESC) AS RowNumber
        From T
        Where A == 'xx' && B == 'XX' && RunDate <= 'dddd'
    ) AS t
Where t.RowNumber=1
```

I tried

**LINQ**

```
T.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => x.Product == "XXX" && x.ProductSubCode == "AAA" && x.RunDate <= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.A,x.B,x.C,x.D})    
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.RunDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList()
```

This can only run in EF Core 6 but can't run in **EF Core 5**.
Now I want to know how to implement above SQL in **EF Core 5**?
And it can run in EF Core 6, but will generate a very complex sql, I also want to know there is a better way to solve this case?
**LINQ generated SQL**

```
SELECT [t0].[RunDate], [t0].[A], [t0].[B], [t0].[C], [t0].[D], [t0].[E]
FROM (
    SELECT [m].[A], [m].[B], [m].[C], [m].[D]
    FROM [T] AS [m]
    WHERE (([m].[A] = N'XXX') AND ([m].[B] = N'AAA')) AND ([m].[RunDate] <= DATEADD(day, CAST(0.0E0 AS int), GETDATE()))
    GROUP BY [m].[A], [m].[B], [m].[C], [m].[D]
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t1].[RunDate], [t1].[C], [t1].[D], [t1].[E], [t1].[A], [t1].[B]
    FROM (
        SELECT [m0].[RunDate], [m0].[A], [m0].[B], [m0].[C], [m0].[D], [m0].[E], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [m0].[A], [m0].[B], [m0].[C], [m0].[D] ORDER BY [m0].[RunDate] DESC) AS [row]
        FROM [T] AS [m0]
        WHERE (([m0].[A] = N'XXX') AND ([m0].[B] = N'AAA')) AND ([m0].[RunDate] <= DATEADD(day, CAST(0.0E0 AS int), GETDATE()))
    ) AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[row] <= 1
) AS [t0] ON ((([t].[A] = [t0].[A]) AND ([t].[B] = [t0].[B])) AND ([t].[C] = [t0].[C])) AND (([t].[D] = [t0].[D]) OR ([t].[D] IS NULL AND [t0].[D] IS NULL))
GO
```

Comment: *Don't* try to generate SQL indirectly. Either use the exact function from DbFunctions if it's available, or write an actual SQL query. You may be able to use that query with `FromSqlRaw` as the starting point for a larger LINQ query. EF Core 6 works this way because an optimization was added for that case.

Comment: If EF Core 6 works, why not use it? .NET 5 reaches End-Of-Life in May, only a couple of weeks away. .NET Core 3.1 reaches EOL on November 2022. You have to migrate anyway

Comment: I would switch to LinqToDB. This ORM has built-in support for [analytic functions](https://linq2db.github.io/articles/sql/Window-Functions-%28Analytic-Functions%29.html). Or at least use the [linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db.EntityFrameworkCore) extension. It is on the recommended list: [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/).